# Do you need an Access Card to travel with the SL app in Stockholm?

Tags: public-transport, mobile-apps, stockholm

Two of us will only need 24 hours of public transport in Stockholm in June. We have the SL App on one of our mobiles, with which we planned to buy two x 24hour passes when needed.  Do we also need physical SL Access Cards?

If not, since we will always travel together, can both of us share one mobile app at Metro stations - or will we have to use the manual gates (which are slower)?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a physical access card when using mobile tickets - that's why we have them.

You can have multiple tickets on the same phone.

As with the access cards; when you're multiple people traveling on the same travel token (i.e. access card, mobile phone) **you have to use the manned kiosks  and on the bus tell the bus driver**.

Comment: The automatic gates don't work with multiple people on a single phone. All commuter train and metro station have mobile phone readers. Source in Swedish: http://www.mynewsdesk.com/se/sl/news/fritt-fram-att-blippa-mobilen-i-alla-spaerrar-372999

Comment: As of spring '21 there are now more phone ticket options. Information in English: https://sl.se/en/in-english/fares--tickets/smart-phone-ticket-app/